# Remap "Ctrl+l" to "Alt+d" with Autohotkey (W7 Pro SP1)

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I want to remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd> to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> so I can highlight the filepath when I'm in Explorer. However, all my attempts have been unsuccessful.

`LCtrl & l::LAlt & d`

Returns:

```
^l::
    !d
return
```

Doesn't work.

```
^l::!d
```

Doesn't work either.

```
LCtrl & l::LAlt & d
```

Returns:

```
Error at line 12.
Line Text: LAlt & d
Error: This line does not contain a recognized action.

The program will exit.
```

But I have used that expression in other scripts and tested it.

Which is the right way to achieve this?

Comment: Off-topic; belongs on [su]

Comment: [However...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autohotkey)

Comment: Idk, maybe you need to provide more info.  For me, both `Ctrl+L` and `Alt+D` take me to the file path in Explorer.  But, I am on Win 8.1.  I do know that Windows has changed the Explorer window class -- but only for some folders/cases (I haven't got the full pattern, yet), so some things work differently in some windows than others.  See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150619-00/?p=45341

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This AutoHotkey script should do what you require.
Tested on Windows 7.

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class CabinetWClass
^l::
#IfWinActive, ahk_class ExploreWClass
^l::
SendInput !d
Return
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot.